# Recursively finding a path through a maze c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have been working to solve this for hours now. I am looking to use a recursive function to solve a maze that is given by the user input. The structure of the maze looks like this:

```
##########          
#  ###   #
#  #     #
#        #
#    o   #
#        #
##########   

        bool searchMaze(int currR, int currC)
        if (currR > (rows-1) || currC > (columns-1) || currR < 0 || currC < 0)
            return false;
        if (maze[currR][currC] == "o")
            return true;
        if (maze[currR][currC] == "#")
            return false;
        maze[currR][currC] = "+";

        if (searchMaze((currR - 1), currC) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (searchMaze(currR, (currC + 1)) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (searchMaze((currR + 1), currC) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (searchMaze(currR, (currC - 1)) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        maze[currR][currC] = " ";
        return false;
    }
```

This is my recursive method above and the "o" marks a solution. Every time I run the program I am facing an infinite recursion and get the error

> "Exception thrown at 0x002396DA in projectName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x000A0FFC" and "Unhandled exception at
>   0x002396DA in projectName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0x000A0FFC."

Comment: This would be a good time to learn to use your debugger. I'm guessing you're using Visual Studio, in which case you should just be able to click the "run in debugger" button somewhere, and it will run your program, and when it's about to crash, it should pause the program instead and point out where it's crashing.

Comment: Yes, I am using VS 2017. Unfortunately, the debugger isn't showing me where the issue is. It gives me the errors I put in my question but I think the main issue is the recursion being infinite. I have tried to locate why the recursion is infinite but have had trouble finding it. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You can speed up the algorithm by a lot if you delete the line `maze[currR][currC] = " ";` so that once you explore a position you never come back to it. This works because no matter how you got to a position, exploring it is pretty much going to get the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the missing case:

```
if (maze[currR][currC] == "+")
    return false;  // Already visited
```

You are tracing back the already visited trail and making no use of `'+'` marks traced by you causing the infinite recursion and the iterations are not converging.

Comment: This solved it for me, I cannot believe it was so simple! I really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You never checked if you are looking at a spot that you have already explored before. You set the current path to "+"s, but you never actually checked for it in the function. Add an if statement to have the function not recurse if the current position is marked "+".

By the way, you can speed up your algorithm a lot by not setting the path back to " " when you backtrack so that once a position is explored you don't ever come back to it. This works because it does not matter where you came from, it only matters if there is a path starting from that position.